# Update number in database according to no

Tags: php, mysql, database, checked, checkedlistbox

I have a `table` which contains lines from `0 ->1000` and i call those numbers `'nu'`. In my database i have some `boxes` which they contain all the same number = `0` . If someone checks in the `check boxes` in the php site that number becomes `1`. My problem starts here, i have achieved to change the number from `0 ->1` after clicking but only if i specifically change which 'nu' to change. Anyway what i want is, to change any box from 0 -> 1.

What works:

```
$query = "UPDATE my_database SET checked = 1 WHERE nu = '1'";//as i said before only if i specify the 'nu' it changes

mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('MySQL Error');
```

EDIT:

It is a simple table with

a)row number at first as `nu`

b)the checkboxes

c) a string just for illustrator purposes

And the nunmber of each row can be identified with the `nu` which differs in every row

Comment: Can you post the db schema (in the original post, not a comment)? And please elaborate on which row exactly you want to change - how can it be identified?

Comment: If you're unhappy changing one at a time, do you want to change more than one at a time?  Maybe all of them?

Comment: Maybe you didn't get me. I can't find a way how to change number for each line. Because if i say a `nu = '2'` then i does only change 0 to 1 only in line 2 and if i say 
`$query = "UPDATE my_database SET checked = 1 WHERE nu";`  it change 0 to 1 for the whole database.

Comment: I really hope you understand me

Comment: Can you provide some sample data before and desired results after the action?  I don't fully get what you want to do.

Comment: never mind I almost solved my problem using post method(AJAX)